# What init happens when one is ommitted

Tags: python

Take the following example:

```
class Account:
    """A simple account class"""

    def __init__(self, owner, amount=0):
        """
        This is the constructor that lets us create
        objects from this class
        """
        self.owner = owner
        self.amount = amount
        self._transactions = []
```

I can initialize it as:

```
a = Account()
```

If an `__init__` it entirely ommitted, what is the "standard initialization" that occurs to create that object? In other words, how does python create the object if there is not init (is there, for an example, a placeholder init that is called if one isn't supplied?), or something that happens pre- or post- init to make sure that the instance is properly created?

Comment: `__new__` is called (under the hood), then - `__init__`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest thanks, would you want to explain how that works a bit behind the scenes in an answer?

Comment: read this https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization. For your another question about `repr/str` - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__